# Kubernetes `local` PV and directory creation

Tags: kubernetes, docker-volume, persistent-volumes

When configuring a `local` PV I noticed there is no option to explicitly create the PV directory on the underlying node if it does not already exist, unlike an `hostPath` PV which provides the `DirectoryOrCreate` option (as shown in the doc [here](https://kubernetes.io/fr/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)), a `local` PV requires you to first create the directory manually and give it the correct ownership and permissions.

I am trying to use a `local` PV with a directory as a mounted local storage device with this code:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pv-volume
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 4Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: "/var/jenkins_home"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - worker-1
```

However, in order for the PV to be configured correctly, I first need to ssh into the `worker-1` node and run the following commands:

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /var/jenkins_home
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/jenkins_home
```

Would it be possible to create the directory and give it the correct ownership and permissions *when* the PV configuration is applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot skip this step.

However you can write script which will work in the background and execute commands which will create directory for local volume and assign rights to it.  Remember to give execute permission to your script.
For example, create script with proper commands then create  [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) which will run created script in also ConfigMap will configure PV.

See example: [configmap-volume](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/use-a-local-disk-through-localvolume-provisioner-in-a-kubernetes-cluster_594930), [configmap-scripts](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71356).